# Should I unwrap the cat?

Tags: fallen-london

A kind friend gave me a cat in a box. When I opened the box, I found out that the cat was almost fully unwrapped. I have the option to fully unwrap the cat, but it says that the odds are against me. Is there a better chance to unwrap it or a reason to wait, or should I just do it now?

Comment: Just to make sure everything is clear, it's _probably_ a cat.

Comment: This has got to be the strangest question I've ever read...

Answer (score 7):

The box is a gamble. As it says, the odds are against you. That said, for a long while, things in Fallen London won't be *too* dangerous. You are meant to be curious and explore to get a sense of the place and how it works.

The box may also have more uses later on in the game, but I don't suggest holding on to this particular one. There will be more, believe me.

Answer (score 5):

Currently the only thing you can do with "A Nearly Unwrapped Cat", is to open it.

As the description says, the odds are against you here, and there is a good chance you'll end up with a negative outcome.

The possible rewards, however, are quite useful, and outweigh the risks for most players.